# JNLP to install an extension JAR

Tags: jvm, java, jnlp, java-web-start

We need to package an extension jar file when deploying a Java client with webstart. The extension jar need to be installed under `jre/lib/ext` and make it available to the java client when started by WebStart.

I managed to copy the files to the right location, but the problem I was facing was that after I installed the extension jar under `lib/ext`, I needed to restart the client JVM in order to pick up the new jar.

How to avoid needing to restart the JVM?

Comment: The problem I was facing was that after I installed the extension jar under lib/ext, I needed to restart the client JVM in order to pick up the new jar. Not sure how to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, yes the second question is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to avoid needing to restart the JVM?

You can't AFAIU.  Classloaders typically do not reload classes or other resources, and I imagine it would be impossible or impractical to change the bootstrap & other JRE related classloaders (or change them soon enough to make a difference).

An alternate strategy might be to:

- Check for the presence of the resources
- If not found, presume they were installed using an `installer-desc` extension this run and:

  - Call [`BasicService.showDocument(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL%29) using the JNLP URL to start a new instance.
  - Call `System.exit(0)` on the current instance to end it.

It might pay to pop a `JOptionPane` to confirm the restart.  E.G.

> To encode OGG right away, restart the app.
>   Restart?
>
> <kbd>OK</kbd> <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

As an aside.  It is generally advised to ***not*** put archives into any directory of the JRE.